# Отладка Bash скрипта

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, github

Задачей является написать универсальный Bash скрипт для Ubuntu, чтобы каждый пользователь мог только одной командой установить программу, также создать сервисный файл. (Пример команды: `cd $HOME && wget -O $HOME"/gearfinal.sh" https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Zhoas/gearnodetesttest/main/gearfinal.sh | bash && chmod +x gearfinal.sh && bash gearfinal.sh`)

Проблема: Код выдаёт ошибку и не может запустить программу, потому что не находит нужный файл в папке, я не знаю, где поменять папку, чтобы все заработало

код:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install -y git clang curl libssl-dev llvm libudev-dev

echo "Press 1 when the selection window appears"
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
source ~/.cargo/env
rustup default stable
rustup update
rustup update nightly
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly

#добавление названия ноды
echo "write your node name ↓↓↓"
read NAME


echo "installing gear node..."
cd
git clone https://github.com/gear-tech/gear.git
cd gear
make node-release



wget -q -O -P $HOME"/gear-node.service" "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Zhoas/gearnodetesttest/main/gear-node.service"


sudo cp gear-node /root
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start gear-node
systemctl status gear-node
journalctl -n 100 -f -u gear-node
```

Гайд для установки программы: https://resilient-climb-223.notion.site/Gear-d03b678e6c624459b7c278dfdc8a1ccb или https://teletype.in/@papadritta/T4H0nJEzLye

[image: Вывод терминала:]

Comment: `sh -x ...your script...`

Comment: А если по делу, то вам нужен ansible.

Comment: @0andriy я новичок еще, куда конкретно и что нужно добавить или поменять? Проблема в том, что скрипт не качает сервисный файл, а сам скрипт запускается

Comment: Суть совета в том, что добавьте опцию `-x` в команду запуска скрипта `bash -x gearfinal.sh`. Она приведет к тому, что перед выполнением каждой команды, команда будет выведена на экран. Так вы поймете, где работает не так, как должно (или как вы ожидаете).

Comment: @RomanKonoval Выводит: root@maining:/home/roman# cp $HOME && wget -O $HOME"/gearfinal.sh" https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Zhoas/gearnodetesttest/main/gearfinal.sh | bash && chmod +x gearfinal.sh && bash -x gearfinal.sh
cp: после '/root' пропущен операнд, задающий целевой файл
По команде «cp --help» можно получить дополнительную информацию.

Comment: Мне страшно давать вам советы. Вы работаете под рутом и вводите команды с опечатками. Это приведет к порче или потере данных.

Comment: @RomanKonoval ничего страшного, на отдельном носителе стоит все

Comment: Поддерживаю @RomanKonoval и @0andriy. Тебе определённо нужно добавить прослойку в виде `ansible`. Такую пелёнку поддерживать дальше будет только тяжелее.

Comment: Вы запускаете `cp $HOME`, да ещё и из-под root. То есть вы запустили `sh -x`, у вас открылась новая сессия, в которой вы опечатались. Вы точно скрипт так пытаетесь отладить?